# Rails Webpacker no longer emitting CSS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, css-loader, webpacker

I upgraded webpacker from (4.0.0.pre.3) to (4.0.2) and it doesn't seem to be emitting my CSS any longer. The screenshot shows the emit log with (4.0.0.pre.3) and(4.0.2) on the right.

[image]

My `App.jsx` is my entry point and it's importing a `app.scss`. I have the following in my `babel.rc`

```
{
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-react',
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
      targets: "last 2 versions"
    }]
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from',
    ['react-css-modules', {
      'filetypes': {
        '.scss': {
          'syntax': 'postcss-scss'
        }
      },
      'generateScopedName': '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
    }]
  ]
}
```

`config/webpack/environment.js`:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')

const customCssLoaderOptions = {
  localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
  // minimize: environment.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  modules: true
}

const CSSLoader = environment.loaders.get('sass').use.find(el => el.loader === 'css-loader')

CSSLoader.options = merge(CSSLoader.options, customCssLoaderOptions)

environment.config.set('entry.App', './app/javascript/packs/App.jsx')

module.exports = environment
```

I commented out the `minimize` option because it was causing the new version to break but I don't think that's causing my CSS to not be emitted altogether?

`config/webpack/development.js`:

```
const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the exact issue, but according to the [Webpacker 4.x upgrade guide](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/v4-upgrade.md) you're meant to replace a `.babelrc` file with a `babel.config.js` (amongst other changes).

I'm upgrading to 4.x also, however, and still not getting CSS emits even after all the steps described in that guide. If you managed to solve the issue, please return to share how.

EDIT:

My colleague just informed me that CSS files (in our Rails + Webpacker codebase, at least) now need to be `filename.module.css`, with the `import` statement updated to match of course.

Hope that helps someone else!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why Webpacker 4+ doesn't emit CSS files but you can emit them by updating line 20 in your `config/webpacker.yml` setting `extract_css` as `true`.

```
 19 # Extract and emit a css file
 20 extract_css: true
```

Comment: Setting extract_css to true no longer seems to do anything, or at least nothing I can see in my export. All CSS files maintain the same hash, even after making changes to them.